# How to update SalesForce object values to null in CastIron orchestration

Tags: salesforce, integration

We are using IBM WebSphere CastIron to integrate SalesForce with external systems. It works ok. 
However I can't seem to be able to set fields to null in an update/upsert operation. Do you know any way  to do this?

In Apex there is a fieldsToNull string property to specify the fields, however it seems like the CastIron connector doesn't support this.

Assigning null to the field does nothing - it is documented in SF API, but I was hoping CastIron will do magic here.

Anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: So are you calling the Salesforce APIs from CastIron or CastIron from Salesforce?

Comment: I'm using the built in SalesForce connector in CastIron to access SF.

Answer (score 0):

Data loader has an option to allow inserting null values. If the option is checked then it will override the existing value in the field with null. If it si not checked it will maintain the existing value if no new value is provided during an update.Check for similar option in Cast Iron.